# Algorithm for maximum non-dominated set

Tags: algorithm, geometry

FInd an algorithm for the next problem : 
Given set S of n points in the 2D plane, a point (x1, y1) dominates another point (x2, y2) if x1 > x2 and y1 > y2. Find the largest set of points M such that M is a subset of S and no point of M is dominated by another point of S.

Comment: A nice little problem, thanks.

Comment: user1256960, I edited the question by adding set names S and M.  In the last sentence, change  “another point of M” to “any point of S” if that is what you mean.  (The original question was ambiguous about whether the other points are in S or in M.)

Comment: This is basically a maximum independent set problem on a constrained graph. The general problem is NP-complete, so you can't get worse than `O(2^n)`.

Answer (score 9):

Sort all points by increasing x coordinates. If two points have the same x coordinate, sort them by decreasing y coordinates. Now, it can be shown that a subset of points is non-dominated if and only if their y coordinates are non-increasing in our sorted sequence, meaning each y coordinate is less than or equal to the previous one in the subsequence.

So the algorithm would be:

1. Sort the points as described above. Time: O(n*logn).
2. Find the longest non-increasing subsequence of y coordinates. Time: O(n*logn). This can be done by adapting the algorithm for finding the [longest increasing subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).

This gives the largest possible set in O(n*logn).

Comment: I believe #2 should ask for the "longest non-increasing subsequence", isn't it so?

Comment: The actual problem asks that no point of M is dominated by another point in S.

Comment: @user1256960 Well, it would be nice if you had said that yesterday. Are you sure about this? It makes the problem pretty simple and a lot less interesting: You just need to return the set of non-dominated points.

Answer (score 3):

There is a divide and conquer algorithm which does this in O(n*logn) time.

Let's divide the points into two halfs, of size n/2 each, based on their x co-ordinates. We find the non-dominated point set in both the halfs. You need to observe that  all the non-dominated points found in the right half will exist in our final list.

With this observation we can write our combine step, remove all the non-dominated points in the left half which have y co-ordinate less than highest y co-ordinate of the point in the non-dominated set in the right half. We have the set of non-dominated points.

**Algorithm:**

```
Find the median along x axis - O(n) time
Find non-dominated points in the left half - T(n/2) 
Find non-dominated points in the right half - T(n/2)
set of non-dominated points could be on O(n) so, the combine step might have to check O(n) points
```

**Equation for time :**

```
 T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n) which is O(n*logn)
```

You can improve this further to O(n*logH) where H is the number of non-dominated points, it requires more insight into the problem and it is a good extension for you to work on.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool comp(pair<int,int> a,pair<int,int> b) {
    if(a.first<b.first)
        return true;
    else if(a.first==b.first) {
        if(a.second<b.second)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int n,x,y;
    cin>>n;
    vector <pair<int,int>> points;
    vector <int> brr;
    for( int i=1;i<=n;i++ ) {
        cin>>x>>y;
        points.push_back({x,y});
    }
    if(n==1) {
        cout<<"1\n";
        return 0;
    }
    sort(points.begin(),points.end(),comp);
    priority_queue <int> point_y;
    for( int i=n-1;i>=0;i-- ) {
        while(!point_y.empty()) {
            if(point_y.top()>points[i].second)
                point_y.pop();
        }
        if(i>=1&&points[i].first==points[i-1].first) {
            brr.push_back(points[i].second);
        }
        else {
            point_y.push(points[i].second);
            for(int it : brr )
                point_y.push(it);
            brr.clear();
        }
    }
    cout<<point_y.size()<<endl;
}
```

this might help you ..
what i am doing is that . first sort the points `(x1<x2) || (x1==x2&&y1<y2)`
and then iterating from end poping out from priority_queue which having y greater then that point