# Dominant set of points in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer, closest-points

So, if two points A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2) are given, and if x1 <= x2 and y1<= y2, then we say B dominates A. Now, given a lot of points, I wish to find out all the non-dominated points. Trivial approach is compare every point with others and get all non-dominated points. But it's O(n^2). So I tried divide and conquer, pretty straightforward and I get to find that in O(nlogn). Our professor says, it can still be done in O(n). I kind of think it's really not possible. I'm not asking you to solve this for me, but would like to know if there's any 'obvious' way through which I can be sure that it can't be done in O(n) under any conditions? However, if it's really possible, don't answer, maybe give some clue.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010914/algorithm-for-maximum-non-dominated-set). I'm not sure an O(n) algorithm is possible either - as far as I know, there'd have to be a sorting step.

Comment: Is the given list of points ordered in any way?

Comment: I must be missing something in the definition, because it seems it could be solved trivially by running through the unordered points once, remembering the point(s) with the largest x  and those with the largest y. At the end, the points in both sets are not dominated.

Comment: @hatchet (5,0), (4,1), (3,2) - None of those are dominated.

Comment: @Dukeling - thanks, I see what I was missing now.

Comment: @AnoopDixith I was thinking of what Dukeling said in his answer. Intuitively the dominating points form a staircase pattern, going from the point with largest `Y` to largest `X`. If the points are sorted you can just walk these steps.

Comment: Is there anything else you're not telling us? Are there any known bounds for x and y?

Comment: Expected Linear time is possible if the points are randomly distributed. Each pass eliminates all points that are not both to the right of the point with the highest y-val, and above the point with the highest x-val, leaving us with roughly 1/4 the points to consider.

Comment: @DaveGalvin Though that's worst-case quadratic, right?

Comment: Can the data be preprocessed?

Answer (score 2):

If the points are already sorted by one of the coordinates (say the x-coordinate), this can be done in O(n) as follows:

- Process the points from the largest x-coordinate.

  - As you go through them, keep track of the largest y-coordinate.
  - If the current point's y-coordinate is smaller than the largest y-coordinate thus far, it's dominated by another point. Otherwise, it's not dominated, so add it to the output.

If the points aren't already sorted, I don't think there's an O(n) solution (but I suppose we can wait and see).

Comment: In the comparison model for unsorted inputs, the lower bound is Omega(n log n). The proof idea is to have n/2 points at (x, K - x) and n/2 at (x, K - 1 - x) for variable integers x; every correct comparison-based algorithm is forced to determine, for each point of the second type, the insertion index in the "staircase" formed by the points of the first type.

Comment: Make that (x, K - 0.5 - x) instead of (x, K - 1 - x).